# mathml configuration

Tags: tex4ht, mathml

I need a customized mathml coding. `mml:` text should be added globally all `mathml` coding

Current Coding:

```
 <math display="block" class="equation"><mi>a</mi> <mo class="MathClass-bin">+</mo> <msubsup><mrow><mi>b</mi></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow><mrow><mn>3</mn></mrow></msubsup></math>
```

The Current coding should be changed to

```
<mml:math display="block" class="equation"><mml:mi>a</mml:mi> <mml:mo class="MathClass-bin">+</mml:mo> <mml:msubsup><mml:mrow><mml:mi>b</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>3</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msubsup></mml:math>
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
a+b_{2}^{3}
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

My CFG:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,NLM,charset=UTF-8,-xtpipes,NoFonts,no-DOCTYPE,refcaption}

\Configure{section} 
            {\HCode{<section>}}    {\HCode{</section>}} 
            {\HCode{<title>}}      {\HCode{</title>}} 
\Configure{subsection} 
            {\HCode{<subsection>}}    {\HCode{</subsection>}} 
            {\HCode{<title>}}      {\HCode{</title>}} 
\Configure{subsubsection} 
            {\HCode{<subsubsection>}}    {\HCode{</subsubsection>}} 
            {\HCode{<title>}}      {\HCode{</title>}} 

\Configure{textit}{\HCode{<italic>}\NoFonts}{\HCode{</italic>}\EndNoFonts}
\Configure{textbf}{\HCode{<bold>}\NoFonts}{\HCode{</bold>}\EndNoFonts}
\Css{.textsuperscript{font-size:.7rem;}}
\Css{.textsubscript{font-size:.7rem;}}
\Configure{HtmlPar}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

How to get the customized mathml output. How to configure the cfg to get this output. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `xml` prefix for mathml elements with `\Configure{mathml}{prefix}`. You also need to register the prefix in the root element with `xmlns` attribute. Full config file:

```
\Configure{ext}{xhtml}
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,NLM,charset=UTF-8,-xtpipes,NoFonts,refcaption,ext=.xhtml}

\Configure{mathml}{mml:}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"\Hnewline  xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">}}
{\HCode{</html>}}
\Configure{MathClass}{0}{*}{<mml:mi\Hnewline>}{</mml:mi>}{}
\Configure{MathClass}{1}{*}{<mml:mo\Hnewline
             mmlclass="MathClass-op">}{</mml:mo>}{}
\Configure{MathClass}{2}{*}{<mml:mo\Hnewline
             mmlclass="MathClass-bin">}{</mml:mo>}{}
\Configure{MathClass}{3}{*}{<mml:mo\Hnewline
             mmlclass="MathClass-rel">}{</mml:mo>}{}
   \Configure{MathClass}{4}{*}{<mml:mrow
                                     ><mml:mo\Hnewline
             mmlclass="MathClass-open">}
                           {</mml:mo><mml:mrow>}{}
   \Configure{MathClass}{5}{*}{</mml:mrow><mml:mo\Hnewline
             mmlclass="MathClass-close">}
                           {</mml:mo></mml:mrow>}{}
\Configure{MathClass}{6}{*}{<mml:mo\Hnewline
             mmlclass="MathClass-punc">}{</mml:mo>}{}
\Configure{MathClass}{7}{*}{<mml:mn>}{</mml:mn>}
                           {0123456789}     
% \Configure{MathClass}{2}{*}{<mml:mo\Hnewline>}{</mml:mo>}{}
% \Configure{MathClass}{3}{*}{<mml:mn\Hnewline>}{</mml:mn>}{}


\Configure{section} 
            {\HCode{<section>}}    {\HCode{</section>}} 
            {\HCode{<title>}}      {\HCode{</title>}} 
\Configure{subsection} 
            {\HCode{<subsection>}}    {\HCode{</subsection>}} 
            {\HCode{<title>}}      {\HCode{</title>}} 
\Configure{subsubsection} 
            {\HCode{<subsubsection>}}    {\HCode{</subsubsection>}} 
            {\HCode{<title>}}      {\HCode{</title>}} 

\Configure{textit}{\HCode{<italic>}\NoFonts}{\HCode{</italic>}\EndNoFonts}
\Configure{textbf}{\HCode{<bold>}\NoFonts}{\HCode{</bold>}\EndNoFonts}
\Css{.textsuperscript{font-size:.7rem;}}
\Css{.textsubscript{font-size:.7rem;}}
\Configure{HtmlPar}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

the important lines are

```
\Configure{mathml}{mml:}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"\Hnewline  xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">}}
{\HCode{</html>}}
```

for some reason, Firefox doesn't want to display the file correctly with `.html` extension, but it works with `.xhtml`. We can change that with

```
\Configure{ext}{xhtml}
```

which must happen before the `\Preamble` command.

The result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/xhtml-math11-f.dtd" > 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><head> <title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- charset=utf-8,html,xhtml,mathml,NLM,charset=UTF-8,-xtpipes,NoFonts,refcaption,ext=.xhtml --> 
<meta name="src" content="sample.tex" /> 
<meta name="date" content="2015-09-29 19:47:00" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
   <table class="equation"><tr><td> <a 
 id="x1-2r1"></a>
<!--l. 6--><mml:math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="block" mml:class="equation">
                              <mml:mi 
>a</mml:mi> <mml:mo 
mmlclass="MathClass-bin">+</mml:mo> <mml:msubsup><mml:mrow 
><mml:mi 
>b</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow 
><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow><mml:mrow 
><mml:mn>3</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msubsup 
>
</mml:math></td><td class="eq-no">(1)</td></tr></table>

</body></html>
```

and rendering in Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Your solution is really impressive. I got the solution